# Spinning wheel has pauses after each rotation?

Tags: animation

there is a part of my model that I want to be spinning at the same velocity forever. However, every time the wheel turns its full 360 degrees it seems to slow down and stop toward the beginning of each rotation. I assume this is because my first and last keyframes are exactly the same. Outside of calculating the angle that the wheel should be on the last keyframe, is there any way to keep my spinning velocity consistent? Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your keyframes are moving in bezier curves. This causes them to slow down at the beginning and end. You could try going into the Curve editor, selecting all of the keyframes on the curve that corresponds to the rotation of your wheel, key "T" and select linear on the left side of the pop-up menu. This will solve your problem.

Now, instead of continuing to add keyframes until the end of your animation, you can key "Shift+E" choose linear extrapolation, and the rotation will continue forever.

Hope this helps! Happy blending.

Comment: Yes, that helped me perfectly thank you. Do you happen to know about any useful guides on the dopesheet?

Comment: I've almost never used the dope sheet and know next to nothing about it, as I prefer to do my work in the f-curve editor. My first words would be try f-curves, but if you want to use the dope sheet, try searching through here: https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/dope_sheet/index.html In my experience, the Blender Reference Manuel is far more useful and up to date than the Blender Wiki, which is mostly stuck on Version 2.5.